# on change JHTML::_('behavior.calendar')

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla1.5

```
JHTML::calendar(date('Y-m-d'),'assigned_to', 'th_assigned_to', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

How to write a jQuery function to get the value in **assigned_to** on change of the value in calendar.

Comment: Provide the HTML generated on the frontend so that one can create a jQuery function for it.

Comment: @mozami But how? I don't know. can you give me some help. `$('#th_assigned_to').change(function(){ alert("Done!.");});` I tried some thing like that but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to judge without knowing how the HTML is rendered. I had a quick glance at your code, I'd imagine something like below might do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#th_assigned_to').change(function(){
            var value = $("#assigned_to").val();
                    alert(value);   
        });
});
```